# suppose $f$ is real-valued and integrable with respect to $\mu$. Prove $A = \{x: f(x) \neq 0\}$ has $\sigma$ finite measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure, not necessarily $\sigma$-finite, and suppose $f$ is real-valued and integrable with respect to $\mu$. Prove that $A = \{x: f(x) \neq 0\}$ has $\sigma$ finite measure, that is, there exists $F_n \uparrow A$ such that $\mu(F_n)< \infty$ for each $n$.

I'm thinking of letting $F_n = A \cap [-n, n]$, but I'm not sure how to show that $\mu(F_n) < \infty$. I know since the Lebesuge measure of $[-n, n]$ is finite, the Lebesgue measure of $F_n$ is trivially finite, however, would the same be true for any measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to set up some notation, what is meant by a measure $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty]$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$, I mean a function that satisfies that for every sequence of disjoint sets $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathcal{A}$, it is satisfied

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) = \mu( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) $$

from here, it is an elementary proof in most standard texts in measure theory or analysis (for example, Rudin or Cohn) that if $A \subset B$ is satisfied and $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, then

$$ \mu(A) \leq \mu(B).$$

The expression $A \cap [-n,n]$, depending on the domain of $f$, might not even make sense. Suppose that the domain of $f$ is $X$, with measure $\mu$. A detail skipped in Balaji sb's answer is this: set  $F_n = \{ x \in X : |f(x)| > 1/n \}$. Then,
$$  \forall x \in X (\frac{1}{n} \chi_{F_n} \leq |f(x)|) \Longrightarrow \int_{X} \frac{1}{n} \chi_{F_n} d\mu \leq \int_{X} f d\mu$$
which implies $\mu(F_n) < \infty$ because $f$ is integrable. From here, are you able to prove the result?

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

$$F_n = \{ x: |f(x)| > a_n \} $$
Since $f$ is real valued and integrable,
$$\mu(F_n) < \infty$$
Choose $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and hence $F_n \rightarrow A$ and $\mu(F_n) < \infty$.